# How to convert FTPFile into File(java.io.File) using Java

Tags: java, file

I have facing problem while convert `FTPFile` into File (`java.io.File`) using Java.

I have already read couple of blogs for this problem, everybody said `FTPFile` store into local machine then retrieve files from local using `OutputStream`and/or `InputStream` concepts but i don't want store any local place.

How can I convert FTPFile into File without storing FTPFile in local machine.
Ex:

```
for(FTPFile ftpFile : allFiles) {
            // here ,I need convert ftpFile into File    
            // java.io.File file 
}
```

I am waiting for your appropriate answers,
Thanks

Comment: how many files do you have? one or more?

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/list-files-and-directories-recursively-on-a-ftp-server

Comment: I have more than one file , I already gone through above blog which you mention.

Comment: The correct answer is nearly always "don't; pass the `InputStream` instead".

Comment: Chrylis, Can you provide me briefly on same ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to use the File-API to use files on a remote system, an FTP-Server in your case. Is this because you have another API that requires a File as input? If yes could you provide more context? Commons-VFS or a protocol handler could be an alternative.